# How to view Updates Approved date in WSUS server by using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, windows-update

I am able to find the Creation date by using the command `GetUpdateApprovals`.
But I approved the "Update123" to Group1 @ 01,Jan'17 and I approved the same update to Group2 @ 07, Sep'17

This command's output showing the same creation date for both groups.

**Current Output**:

```
Group name       Creation Date
------------------------------------
Group1              07, Sep'17
Group2              07, Sep'17
```

Please guide me to get (output like below) the exact approval date from Powershell.

** Output**:

```
Update 123
    Group name       Approved Date
    ------------------------------------
    Group1              07, Sep'17
    Group2              07, Sep'17
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Or

```
Group name: group 1

Update name                   Approved Date
--------------------------------------------------------------
Update 1                         07,Sep'17
Update 2                         05, Feb'17
```

Comment: I'm using powershell for reporting feature

Comment: Please share the cmdlet which you're firing to get the reports. Also, if you have a SQL Server installation for WSUS Database, you can fetch these details using a SQL query to SUSDB.